# Convert JSON to CSV and save from browser to computer

Tags: php, json, csv, export-to-excel

I have this JSON:

```
{"data":[{"ID":1,"br":"1-2015","kupac":"ADAkolor","datum":"2015-05-19","rok":"2015-05-21","status":"placeno"},{"ID":2,"br":"2-2015","kupac":"Milenk","datum":"2015-05-27","rok":"2015-05-28","status":""}]}
```

How to convert this to CSV file or Exel XLS using php pdo?

Also in this example:

```
if (empty($argv[1])) die("The json file name or URL is missed\n");
$jsonFilename = $argv[1];

$json = file_get_contents($jsonFilename);
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$firstLineKeys = false;
foreach ($array as $line)
{
    if (empty($firstLineKeys))
    {
        $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
        fputcsv($f, $firstLineKeys);
        $firstLineKeys = array_flip($firstLineKeys);
    }
    // Using array_merge is important to maintain the order of keys acording to the first element
    fputcsv($f, array_merge($firstLineKeys, $line));
}
```

where I need to put my $jsonTable ?

Comment: Do you know what php pdo is used for?! I guess not, otherwise you wouldn't want to use it to convert json to csv.  http://php.net/manual/fr/class.pdo.php

Comment: Ok, I just need to convert JSON to Excel format

Comment: $out = fopen('php://output', 'w'); fputcsv($out, $jsonTable); fclose($out);

Comment: Check [here](https://gist.github.com/Kostanos/5641110) for a simple JSON to CSV solution.

Comment: I guess you should add what you've tried to the question and not as a comment, also, you should read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the pdo part, but to write it to a file you would do something like this

```
$json = '{"data":[{"ID":1,"br":"1-2015","kupac":"ADAkolor","datum":"2015-05-19","rok":"2015-05-21","status":"placeno"},{"ID":2,"br":"2-2015","kupac":"Milenk","datum":"2015-05-27","rok":"2015-05-28","status":""}]}';

$out = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach(json_decode($json, true)['data'] as $key => $value) {
  fputcsv($out, $value);
}
fclose($out);
```

Comment: hm, nothing happend when I try this code, just blank screen

Comment: This works just fine, I just tested it again.  You do need to make sure you have proper permissions on the folder/file that you are attempting to write to.  Otherwise it will fail, but that is not unique to my solution and will be the case regardless of the solution you choose.  If the csv file is not being generated, you should look at your php error log.  You will most likely have a 'permission denied' warning.

Answer (score 1):

Use  [JSON2CSV](https://github.com/danmandle/JSON2CSV)

> A simple PHP script to convert JSON data to CSV

example usage:

```
php json2csv.php --file=/path/to/source/file.json --dest=/path/to/destination/file.csv
```

OR You can have it dump the CSV file relative to the PHP script:

`php json2csv.php --file=/path/to/source/file.json`

Comment: Ok, that nice, but I create JSON dinamicly when calling getracuni.php file, so that file give me JSON data. How I can integrate this with your code ?

Comment: Also when I try with this data: {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]} the downloaded CSV file is blank... maybe its server probem or php version